# Painting over a VideoView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to allow the user of my app to paint (with their finger) over a VideoView object.

I have had little success.

In my current attempt, I have tried to put a SurfaceView over a VideoView though I have reached a number of issues: When I open a navigation drawer, the drawings, appear OVER the navigation drawer interface; and the drawings seem to blink on an actual device ( they flash).

This is just my attempt, I am sure there is a better way of allowing the user to paint.

```
    <VideoView
       android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       </VideoView>


    <com.example.example.VideoOverlay
        android:id="@+id/videooverlay"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is the VideoOverlay Class

```
public class VideoOverlay extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Thread thread = null;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Random random;

    public void onResumeMySurfaceView(){
           running = true;
           thread = new Thread(this);
           thread.start();
          }

          public void onPauseMySurfaceView(){
           boolean retry = true;
           running = false;
           while(retry){
            try {
             thread.join();
             retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
          }

    public VideoOverlay(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        random = new Random();
        this.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    }
    public VideoOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        random = new Random();
        this.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    }
    public VideoOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        random = new Random();
        this.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }
// Other stuff

      @Override
      public void run() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       while(running){
        if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
         Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
         //... actual drawing on canvas

         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

         int w = canvas.getWidth();
         int h = canvas.getHeight();
         int x = random.nextInt(w-1); 
         int y = random.nextInt(h-1);
         int r = random.nextInt(255);
         int g = random.nextInt(255);
         int b = random.nextInt(255);
         paint.setColor(0xff000000 + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b);
         canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);

         surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
      }
      }

}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: First, you should definitely enable hardware acceleration in your *Android Manifest*. Second - consider using a different UI pattern - such as *ActionBar* button, or the [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have enabled hardware acceleration though, there still appears to be some flashing.